# 'The requested URL was not found on the server'

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello world"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8000, debug=True)
```

While clicking the link http://0.0.0.0:8000/,  it is showing:

```
> The requested URL was not found on the server If you entered the URL
> manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Comment: **/** is default url, u haven't defined route for default url instead try **/hello**

Answer (score 1):

The only URL you have defined is `/hello`, so when you request `/`, there is nothing to be served, so you get the `Not Found` Error. You'll need to either define something for `/` or use `http://0.0.0.0:8000/hello` instead. E.g.,

```
@app.route('/')
def index_view():
    return "hello from index"
```